# How to create .pdf, write to it and save it with JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing

I created a `ArrayList<Pair<Integer,Integer>>` and saved some data into it. I am unable to figure out a way to write it to a pdf and then save it using JFileChooser.

I tried the same thing with a .txt and it works perfectly but it does not seem to work the same way with .pdf.

Comment: Can you post some code showing what you are trying to do? The JFileChooser class has nothing to do with creating the contents of a pdf file.  It is used to allow a user to locate a path into a file structure.

Comment: *".. then save it using JFileChooser."* Can you save it to a hard coded file name / path? If not, this has nothing to do with Swing or `JFileChooser`. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use external libraries for writing pdf. As txt files contains just plain text you can write anything into it, but pdf follows some rules.

One of the library you can use is [Apache's pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/).

> and then save it using JFileChooser.

For this you can use `JFileChooser` object, get the save file path and pass it to the pdfbox's `save()` method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you use PDFBox, then download the source code and look at the examples subdirectory. A good start is HelloWorldTTF.java . Or look in the tools subproject and see the TextToPDF.java tool. (also available as a command line tool as part of pdfbox-app )